# Backbone, Require, Jasmine view not rendering

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine

For the life of me I can't seem to get my view to render HTML within a Jasmine test. I have been following all the tutorials I can find but nothing is working.

```
require(['../js/app', '../js/views/demand/match'], function(App, Match) {
    App.initialize();

    beforeEach(function() {
        this.view = new Match();
    });

    describe("Instantiation", function() {
        it("returns the view object", function() {
           expect(this.view.render()).toEqual(this.view);
        });

        it("produces the correct HTML", function() {
            this.view.render();
            var expectedHtml = '<a href="MatchLink"><h2>MatchLinkTitle</h2></a>';
            expect(this.view.el.innerHTML).toEqual(expectedHtml);
        });
    });
});
```

The above code always has a blank innerHTML property. The HTML associated to the match.js (match.html) file isn't showing up at all. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Seems not ok: expect(this.view.render()).toEqual(this.view);

Comment: It will fail that test but the real point is that the this.view.el.innerHTML is always blank.

Comment: There's no way for us to know what's wrong without seeing the code for `Match`.

Comment: There are some strange things in your test, first why you need to start App. As this is a unit test and you use requiresjs there is no need for external dependencies. Your first test should use `toBe` as you wanna check if both are the same instances of  `Match`. And we need to see what Match does in its render function to help you with this problem.